# PHP+HTML webform to be emailed in PDF format as attachment

Tags: php, pdf

I recently have a project, I am creating a booking system.
there's only one thing that I need to do to finish it.

I want my web form to be converted into a dynamic PDF file.
Means, when a user makes a booking, he will fill up the web form, after all fields are filled up, it will be saved to the database and the web form will be converted to PDF that will be email to the client's email address.

Is there a plug-in that I need to use? How can I make my form be converted to PDF and be sent to user??
If there is, can you kindly give me a link to it?

I would gladly appreciate any help from you guys.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the libary TCPDF to accomplish this. The libary can create a PDF from HTML including HTML forms. Look at this example, it will help you farther:

- PDF Example: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_014.pdf
- PHP tutorial of PDF example: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_014.phps
- Download link of TCPDF: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/